# Python and the Airtable API

Tags: python, api, airtable

Can anyone find an exampple of the API for [Airtable.com](http://www.airtable.com) being used in python. 
There is documentation but I'm not sure how to get started.

Note, they don't have a client library.

Comment: I would like to add the tag `airtable` to this, but don't have enough rep to create a new tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one project on github:

https://github.com/nicocanali/airtable-python

> **Airtable Python**
>   Python interface to the Airtable's REST API - https://airtable.com

Comment: Hi Could you let me know any GUI for airtable

Comment: @Ashh If you mean web gui - im recommend vue.js (+vuetify). A bit outdated example of using vue.js with data from airtable - https://medium.com/row-and-table/an-basic-intro-to-the-airtable-api-9ef978bb0729

Comment: How can I use airtable with nodejs? Is there any project you can share with me please

Answer (score 5):

I made one similar to the original one by nicocanali but organized slightly different: https://github.com/gtalarico/airtable-python-wrapper